# Can Gerrit go Out-Of-Sync

Tags: git, gerrit

I am new to Git and Gerrit.

I want to know if I make first few commits via Gerrit and then make some commits directly to Git by bypassing Gerrit will it result in Gerrit going out-of-sync?

Will further commits will have some problem because of direct commits?

Comment: Please [don't use signatures or taglines in your posts](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#signatures).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Checking the docs, looks like the answer is [no; this is supported](https://gerrit-review.googlesource.com/Documentation/user-upload.html#bypass_review).

Answer (score 2):

No there will not be any problem. But you might need to rebase your previously uploaded changes before you merge them [ In case if parent of those CLs changes because of the bypassed changes ]. Other than this you may face conflicts when trying to merge your changes. There will not be any effect on future commits..

Comment: I have two questions:

a) What you mean by "you might need to rebase your previously uploaded changes before you merge them". 

Generally Before any commit, a normal fetch and rebase from git repository will be done.

b) What is mean by "you may face conflicts when trying to merge your changes".

Does here the merge means merge of other commits from Gerrit To Git or something else?

Comment: a) Rebase in the the sense you need to cherry pick your change on your local machine and push that change again on gerrit. It is required only if the parent of your CL uploaded on gerrit changes.    b) Suppose you bypass gerrit and merge CL1 which modifies line no 10 in File1 and you have a change uploaded on gerrit which is also modifies same line in same file. now if you try to merge this change gerrit will show you conflicts and will not allow you to merge your change.

Comment: a) It seems to be a general problem where one needs to rebase the changes before commit, even if the gerrit is being used, one has to rebase its changes to point to correct parent changelist. b) The example situation given by you can also arise while using gerrit, If the first change list modifies line no 10 in File1 and is still in gerrit and the second commit also modifies the same line, the second commit will have conflict. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: yes correct.. Gerrit is just for code review. If you see other way its just a UI for your projects/branches etc..